# Minted PHP with line numbers

Tags: minted, line-numbering

I've added `minted` and inserted PHP code. The result is that I must put `< ?php` and `?>` tags to get the code colored, then if I want to display line numbers it starts from `< ? php` line like below:

```
1 < ? php
2 echo "abcd"
3 ? >
```

I don't want to have line numbers in the first and the last line and I don't like to put it all in the same line.

this is the code from minted documentation:

```
\r\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\sffamily
\textcolor[rgb]{0.5,0.5,1.0}{\scriptsize
\oldstylenums{\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}}
\begin{minted}[linenos]{php}
<?php
echo "abcd"
?>
\end{minted}
```

Anyone have solution for this?

**SOLUTION**

we use the firstline and lastline options to hide the  tags.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have you tried omitting the `<?php` and using the `startinline` option?

Comment: it is actually with the firstline and lasline options.. thanks anyway

Comment: @G.Poore `startinline` works for me. Not tested `firstline`, but what I read from [documentation](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) this should work too.